# Displaying total for each row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables and I am trying to build a data report.

I was able to find a solution for the columns totals in the footer by using `footerCallback`, but I was not able to find a solution to get totals at the end of each row.

After quite a bit of research and trials and errors, I came up with some code that works using `rowCallback`, however, this does not seems efficient.

Here is the section in my dataTable.

```
"rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
    var tr = jQuery(row);
    var d = tr.children(".sum");
    var a= [];
    var c = jQuery.each(d, function(i,v){
        a.push(v.innerText);
    });
    sum = a.reduce(function(a, b) {
        var x = parseFloat(a) || 0;
        var y = parseFloat(b) || 0;
        return x + y;
    }, 0);

    jQuery('td:eq(4)', row).html( sum );
},
```

The cells (td) that needs to be included in the sum have a class of sum.
Like I said, this works, but, there has to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: If your data is coming from the server and is static, you can perform calculation on the server and display it as another data column rather than perform it on the client.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gyrocode but here is my solution that sums rows and columns based.

```
                var mydt = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, { a: 5, b: 6, c: 7, d: 8 }, { a: 10, b: 12, c: 13, d: 14 }];

                $(function ($) {
                    //  $("#tbl").DataTable({ columns: [{ data: "id" }, { data: "text" }], dom: "tB", buttons: [{ text: "Load Me", action: function (e, dt, node, config) { loadme(e, dt, node, config); } }] });

                    $("#tbl2").DataTable({
                        data: mydt, columns: [{ data: "a" }, { data: "b" }, { data: "c" }, { data: "d" },
                            {
                                data: function (xx, yy, zz, dd) {
                                    var rt = 0;
                                    $.each(xx, function (item, val) { rt += val; });
                                    return rt;
                                }
                            }],
                        initComplete: function (aaa, bbb, ccc) {
                            var th = $("#tbl2 tfoot th");
                            for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                                var sb = 0;
                                var col = $("#tbl2").DataTable().columns(i).data();
                                for (var j = 0; j < col[0].length; ++j) {
                                    sb += col[0][j];
                                }
                                th[i].innerText = sb;
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    );

                }
                );


           <div style="width:500px">
                <table class="display" id="tbl2">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>A</th>
                            <th>B</th>
                            <th>C</th>
                            <th>D</th>
                            <th>t</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                    <th>0</th>
                    <th>0</th>
                    <th>0</th>
                    <th>0</th>
                    <th>0</th>
                    </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
```